# Reduce function javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apexcharts

I want to sum one 'y' variable when 'x' has the same value but in a different object, im using the function reduce in order to achieve it but when i check the console it outputs an empty array.

the issue is that this wouldn't work in apex charts so im stuck in this part. Does anyone know how i could fix it?

```
computed: { 
  cotizacion(){
     this.cotizaciones = {
        name: 'Cotizaciones',
        data: this.info.filter(info => info.estatus == 'cotizacion').reduce((res, i) => {
           res[i.x] = { 
              y: (i.x in res ? res[i.x].y : 0) + i.y,
              x: i.x
           } 
           return res;
        }, [])
     }
     console.log(this.cotizaciones)
     return this.cotizaciones
  },
}
```

in this example it works but without the reduce function

```
venta(){
     this.ventas = {
        name: 'Ventas',
        data: this.info.filter(info => info.estatus == 'cerrado')
     }
     console.log(this.ventas)
     return this.ventas
  },
```

[image]

this is the result in console, the first has the reduce function and doesn't work properly

Comment: unclear why you are using reduce and not map

Comment: Are `this.info.filter(info => info.estatus == 'cotizacion')` really not empty?

Comment: Don't directly change the value of `data property` in `computed` (like `this.cotizaciones`, `this.ventas`). Uses one clone of data property instead or declare one local variable

Comment: @epascarello to be completely honest i found the solution of using the reduce method in another thread, but if you could suggest another way to accomplish it and you could tell me how i would really appreciate it.

Comment: @Anton - No, it shows the objects inside when i open it but in the array count it displays 0 therefore it doesn't work in apexcharts

Comment: @Sphinx - i changed it as you suggested but i still get an error

Comment: `it shows the objects inside when i open it but in the array count it displays 0` - you mean it is not empty in console.log? Or where do you "see" it is not empty?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Ee5xHYp this is what i see in console @Anton

Comment: @JoeldelaFuente very interesting, because first array - it is not array =) it is an object actually. That's why it has length of zero. You are using dates as keys for your object. So of course you can restore indexes by changing `.reduce((res, i)` to `.reduce((res, i, idx)` and `res[i.x] = {` change to `res[idx] = {`, but the idea of using a `.map` was good.